# How is action on JButton being invoked in this code?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, windowlistener

I have problem understanding how is actionListener used in the following code and what is the addWindowListener method doing in the code below:

kindly help me with it .

```
public class SwingListenerDemo {
  private JFrame mainFrame;
  private JLabel statusLabel;

  public SwingListenerDemo(){
    prepareGUI();           }

  public static void main(String[] args){
   SwingListenerDemo  swingListenerDemo = new SwingListenerDemo();  
   swingListenerDemo.showActionListenerDemo();}

   private void prepareGUI(){
     mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
     mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        System.exit(0);
     }        
  });    

    mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
  }

   private void showActionListenerDemo(){

      JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");

    okButton.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());        
    mainFrame.add(okButton);

    mainFrame.setVisible(true);         }

   class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener{
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             statusLabel.setText("Ok Button Clicked.");
                                                      }
                                                       }    
    }
```

Comment: Add 'tutorial' to each of 'jbutton actionlistener windowlistener' separately in your favorite search engine and that should answer your questions.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: exactly.. I suppose this forum is for complicated cases which you cannot find somewhere in the documentation, but NOT for basic questions. A lot of peoply are lazy and it is more comfortable to spam some forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you click on ok button, your `actionPerformed` method will get called as you registered callback on ok button as `okButton.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());`
- When you close your awing window from top right 'X' button, your program will exit with a return code of 0 and that's what your window listener is doing in `windowClosing` method.

Comment: thanks for answer but I can't understand what is System.exit(0); doing in windowClosing method . kindly help me..

Comment: See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) It will terminate your java process with return status as 0.